# Is there an app that can read the clock out loud on a smart TV?

Tags: time-management, health, accessibility, timer, android-tv

I just bought a smart TV with Android for a blind person. Now, he can listen to audio and songs on a flash drive or even from youtube.

I would like to install an app that tells him the time every 15 minutes or so and then the app should close itself and continue what was playing. That would be a very very big advantage for her so that she can take her medicine on time.

Even if there's no app like that, I just need an app the runs a specific audio file every 15 minutes and I'll record my voice telling the clock in our language. It'll be like an alarm, but the tone will be my voice telling the time.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked and found this:
[TellMeTheTime App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=TellMeTheTime.App&hl=en_US)
 Im not sure if it's what you are looking for.

Comment: I'll try this and get back to you